# Design a DFA with following condition.

Tags: computational-mathematics

A DFA that accepts a language in which every odd position of a string is a 1 with inputs as {0,1}

Comment: 1 ( ( 0 | 1 ) 1 ) *

Comment: @Daniel, that's a description of the language, not a DFA. But maybe you are hinting that from that description of the language, it should be easy to construct the DFA.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well I took it for granted all regex are equivalent to DFA, but then again, I can see in hindsight how that is a bad assumption to apply to a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 states - `WAIT` and `OK`. You start in the `WAIT` state and hope to get to the `OK` state, which accepts. Here are the rules:
$$
    \mathrm{WAIT} \overset{1}{\rightarrow} \mathrm{OK}
$$
$$
    \mathrm{OK} \overset{0}{\rightarrow} \mathrm{WAIT}
$$
$$
    \mathrm{OK} \overset{1}{\rightarrow} \mathrm{WAIT}
$$

Comment: And if you're in the WAIT state, and see a zero? I guess there's a "black hole" state, and the convention is not to count it as a state?

Comment: That rises an error - the DFA does not accept the input. You can convert the description into a complete DFA by adding `ERROR` state you mention, but I find that it only clutters the automaton.

Answer (score 0):

[image: State Machine]

All state machines have a starting point.  The top right state represents the "never going to accept" state.  The bottom left state is the necessary accepting state.  The other state is the "seen an even number of inputs and so far so good" state.